# Is there a way to detect a DOM HTMLElement offsetTop property change in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom

I wonder if there is a way to detect if the `offsetTop` property of an `HTMLElement` is changing.

Let's say I have a div above another div. If the div above change it's `offsetHeight` property : then the div below changes it's `offesetTop` property.

It seems like the `MutationObserver` doesn't help in this case. So I simply wonder if it's even possible to create this kind of event.

Any idea ?

**EDIT - Here is the solution, as suggested by [Pavlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7658042/pavlo) : target the parent to get the children changes using the right configuration.**

```
this.observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
  //Do what you want
  for (let mutation of mutations)
    console.log('Mutation detected', mutation);
});

this.observer.observe(this.yourDiv.parentElement, { //Change this.yourDiv by your own HTMLElement.
  attributes: true,
  childList: true, //Important
  subtree: true //Important
});
```

Comment: What's the use-case? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: How the user changed offsetHeight of above div? If you already have one function to do this, why not change offsetTop of below div at the same time in that function?

Comment: Hey! Thank you for these fast answers.
Well I have a UI where pressing a button is changing the size of a div. The div under it has a dynamically calculated height (window.offsetHeight - div.offsetTop).
When this happens I'd just like to detect it so I can adjust the height of the div below.
The stuff is that the div above is a reusable component who is already outputting one value, so I'd prefer to make an event in one file, instead of an output traveling multiple files lol. I'm not stuck I'm just being difficult hah.

Comment: It seems like `MutationObserver` would work if you had this config `var config = { attributes: true, childList: true; subtree: true };` and you set this on the parent, so any changes to the parent and its subtree prompt the callback method to be called

Comment: Really ? Awesome I'll try and tell you!

Comment: This is a theory based on reading the API. I can try to make an example of what i think might work

Comment: It works! Well done buddy, Thank youuuu <3
I miss read the API. childList/subtree is what I needed, they're useful, I'll keep those in mind!

Comment: That's great, happy problem solving :)

Comment: As I understand it, MutationObservers can only observe mutations to the DOM (the HTML) itself, not to computed stylesheet values.
So:
you can monitor the HTML attributes - eg width="100",
you can monitor the immediate child HTML nodes,
you can monitor the subtree of the nodes and attributes under the current element.

You can't directly monitor changes to CSS, unless you also make a change to one of the 3 above things (current element attribute, immediate children, descendents / subtree).

I will attempt to trigger by adding an arbitrary class (an attribute) and see if that can work...